# Date conversion issue in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to convert the payment day field from AUTO_TABLE into a day of the month. The payment day is stored in string format and the first nine days are stored as single character. I want to append a '0' string before the payment day for day 1-9 and convert the resulting string into 'DD'. The query worked for two months, but Oracle throws an error stating "invalid Month" when I attempt to convert the string into a date. How can I convert the payment day into two character decimals and proceed to concatenate day with the current month and year? Thanks for your help.

```
Select case when Payment_Day <> to_char(sysdate, 'dd') 
    then Payment_Day 
    end as Payment_day, 
    Payment_Day2, 
    trunc(sysdate) - 8 as DateEdit2, 
    trunc(sysdate) - 15 DateEdit1

From(
Select case when Payment_Day2 > trunc(sysdate) 
    then Payment_day2 - 31 
    else Payment_Day2 end as Payment_Day2, 
    Payment_Day, theSysdate as theSysdate

From(
Select distinct to_date(Payment_Day2, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as Payment_Day2, 
    Payment_Day, theSysdate

        From(
        Select thePIDM, 
    to_char(DateEdit, 'MM') || '/'  || to_char(Payment_Day, '00') || '/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')  as Payment_Day2, 
    to_char(Payment_Day) as Payment_Day, Trunc(theSysdate) theSysdate

              From (
                    Select distinct PIDM as thePIDM,  
                         to_char(Payment_Day) as Payment_Day, 
                         trunc(sysdate) as DateEdit, 
                         to_char(sysdate, 'DD') as theSysdate

                    from AUTO_TABLE

                    Group by  PIDM, to_char(Payment_Day)

                   )

            )



        Order by Payment_Day2
)



Order by Payment_Day2

)
```

Comment: data sample and desire output help a lot.

Comment: The innermost subquery use both *DISTINCT* and *GROUP BY*. This is not an error, but an overkill. Either option will deliver the same result. Additionally if the payment_day is *string*, you need not transform it to char `to_char(Payment_Day)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The query worked for two months*. Yes you were lucky the run it in July and August, both having 31 days.

The problem is in the line

```
     to_char(DateEdit, 'MM') || '/'  || to_char(Payment_Day, '00') || '/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')  as Payment_Day2,
```

which mix the payment_day with the current month (from sysdate). This leads to invalid dates such as *09/ 31/2015*.

The remedy is in reducing the payment day to the last day of the current month

```
        -- instead of    
        --   to_char(Payment_Day) as Payment_Day,
        -- limit the payment day to the last day of the current month
        to_char(least(to_number(Payment_Day),CAST(to_char(LAST_DAY(sysdate),'dd') AS INT))) as Payment_Day,
```